# How to show or hide only one same class mouseovered element not all of them?

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure out how to show or hide only one element per `mouseover`, not all of them. I am using jQuery. I tried using `this` but with multiple classes that is not an option. Some tips?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function textAppear() {
    $('.solutions-visible').mouseenter(function() {
      $('.btn-solutions-invisible, .solutions-invisible-paragraph').show(500);
      $('.solutions-visible').css("box-shadow", "0px 5px 38.8px 1.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)");
    });
    $('.solutions-visible').mouseleave(function() {
      $('.btn-solutions-invisible, .solutions-invisible-paragraph').hide(500);
      $('.solutions-visible').css("box-shadow", "none");
    });
  }

  textAppear();
});
```

Comment: `I tried using this but with multiple classes that is not an option` I'm not sure why you'd think that, as it is exactly the solution you need: `$('.solutions-visible').css(...` --> `$(this).css(...`. Also note that you can shorten this code by using [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover), [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle) and also by using [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass). The latter is far better practice as it moves the CSS out of the JS code.

Comment: Thank you I have shortened it. But the css function is my least concern. My main problem is div classes with the same name (.btn-solutions-invisible, .solutions-invisible-paragraph). I need to show them one by hover not all of them at once.

Comment: Yep, my comment addressed that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified the code as suggested by @Rory McCrossan. I have wrapped the solutions in a div and then used `$(this)` and `.find()` to select only the elements that are wrapped by the hovered element. This should give you enough to adjust it to your specifications.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.solutions-visible').hover(function() {
    var elements = $(this).find('.solutions');
    elements.toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.solutions {
  opacity:0;
  transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in;
}
.solutions.active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="solutions-visible">
  <p>Show Solution 1</p>
  <p class="solutions solutions-invisible-paragraph">I'm a paragraph</p>
  <button class="solutions btn-solutions-invisible">I'm a button</button>
</div>
<div class="solutions-visible">
  <p>Show Solution 2</p>
  <p class="solutions solutions-invisible-paragraph">I'm a paragraph</p>
  <button class="solutions btn-solutions-invisible">I'm a button</button>
</div>
<div class="solutions-visible">
  <p>Show Solution 3</p>
  <p class="solutions solutions-invisible-paragraph">I'm a paragraph</p>
  <button class="solutions btn-solutions-invisible">I'm a button</button>
</div>
<div class="solutions-visible">
  <p>Show Solution 4</p>
  <p class="solutions solutions-invisible-paragraph">I'm a paragraph</p>
  <button class="solutions btn-solutions-invisible">I'm a button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to combine the find() function with this. You got me on the right track and I completed my code.